# Why does using a share mapped in a static method fail?

Tags: asp.net

I've run into a strange phenomenon. I managed to solve it, but still I'm wondering about the reason as its counterintuitive for me.

In short: In a page load method I used a static method from another class to map a network share. Then in my page load I tried to copy a file onto that share which failed. As it stands it looks like as if the mapping is run under a different user handle (or something similar). When I did exactly the same mapping in my page load method instead of the other static method it worked without a hitch.

Now the question is: What is the reason for this?

Page-load:

```
...
MemoryStream streamReader;
...
myClass.mapdrive();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(@"\\myserver\theshare\myfile.txt"))
{
    StreamUtils.Copy(streamReader, streamWriter, buffer); //<-- Point of Exception (Access Denied)
}
```

**Static:**

```
public class myclass
{
    public static void mapdrive()
    {
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(
                    "net use %1 %2 /USER:%3",
                    @"\\myserver\theshare",
                    "passme",
                    @"\\myserver\myuser"
        );
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me rather like you are already connected to the server under alternate credentials. Try disconnecting from the server prior to attempting to map. (I prefer to discuss this [on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/1437622/web-application-failing-to-map-a-shared-drive).)